# read and process excel data in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I've to read the excel and process the data as per the attached excel below table. I'm able to read the file but not able to proceed further for this logic. Please guide.

Approach:
Need to read rows from A9 cell. Object name will be the main node or label, inside the object node there will be field name and the value of field name will be mentioned in the excel cell#. if the merge with value is there then that will be merge with main node.

Example: For an exmaple object is Contact. There is field "Name" the value of name will be B2 cell means "123". moving further there is another field in the same Contact node and we have to merge this with the above one as mentioned in the merged with value.

expected output:

```
 [{
   "Contact": [{
        "Name": "123",
        "phone1": "223344",
        "phone2": "443322"
    },
    {
        "Name": "666"
    }
   ],
   "Account": [{
         "acNo": "A21"
    }]
 }]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please give further details about what you're trying to achieve once you've loaded the Excel file content? Thank you.

Comment: @olamiral added the further details. kindly advice on that.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the data in one sheet and the data extraction rules in another one?

Comment: @olamiral no both are in same sheet. Please help me out on data extraction atleast

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the example sheet doesn't match what [DataWeave supports for Excel](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-excel) files:

> Only one table is allowed per Excel sheet. A table is expressed as an
> array of rows. A row is an object where its keys are the columns and
> the values the cell content.

It is not clear that it is possible to implement it as desired.